# Server side rendering with puppeteer for PDF or Image screenshot for Angularjs type applications for protected/secured site (pushing the dom

Tags: node.js, angularjs, pdf, puppeteer

I want to be able to do server side rendering and image screenshot capture to pdf for a spa angularjs site. The site is secured so many of the API calls will be protected.

What are some approaches for capturing the entire site and doing this. One approach is to have the code on the server and try to render but the issue here is that the site would be secured so the api calls might fail.

Is it possible to push the dom from front-end to the server side of all of the rendered content?  I have seem simple examples with public type sites and using puppeeter, but not a protected spa that works?